# Powershell CSV file import acting strange

Tags: powershell, office365

I have a CSV file that has information I am tasked with automating in office 365. I  am having trouble specifically with the manager field when trying to import the items from the CSV. the following code works perfectly when only a single entry is in the CSV file, but as soon as I add a econd or third entry the objectID returns null. Is the problem with the loop? It seems to work fine if I use other command-lets like Set-AzureADUser -DisplayName

```
$importFile = "c:\report\Users.csv"
$users = import-csv $importFile | select *


foreach($user in $users){
$DisplayName = $users.'Display Name'
$Managers = $users.'Manager'

$Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName 
$EmployeeManagers = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $Managers

Set-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.ObjectId -RefObjectId $EmployeeManagers.ObjectId
}
```

Comment: In which `foreach` (first or second) you get the `objectId` as `null` ?
You could try printing it in the loop to see each values in in the iteration.

Comment: in the first loop it returns correctly if I only have a single entry in the CSV file. once I add a second entry it returns null   ```foreach($user in $users){ $DisplayName = $users.'Display Name' $Managers = $users.'Manager' $Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName $EmployeeManagers = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $Managers```

Comment: Try to debug in an editor, and make sure you have filled correct `DisplayName` in the `Display Name` column for the second row. Better if you could post the csv here.

Comment: it does match up perfectly. I have debugged in the editor. with a single entry in the CSV file (with a header) it returns correctly, add a second entry and it returns null. The ```$DisplayName``` matches up correctly. the only difference is adding additional entries to the ```Display name``` field in the csv file

Comment: Maybe this would help. CSV file Header ```Display Name``` csv file entry 1 ```user X```  when i try the following ```foreach($user in $users){
$DisplayName = $users.'Display Name'
$Managers = $users.'Manager'

$Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName``` then ```$employees``` returns null if I add ```UserY``` to positon 2 in the CSV file

Comment: to check your changes, use `foreach ($user in $users) {get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $user.objectid} `, not `foreach ($user in $users) {get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.objectid}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in the variable usage in `foreach` . You are using `$Users` inside foreach which will have multiple items. change it to `$user` inside the loop which is the current item.

```
foreach($user in $users){
    $DisplayName = $user.'Display Name'
    $Managers = $user.'Manager'

    $Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName 
    $EmployeeManagers = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $Managers

    Set-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.ObjectId -RefObjectid $EmployeeManagers.ObjectId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! its very close now. The only issue is it is setting every user to the same manager now.

```
$importFile = "c:\report\Users.csv"
$users = import-csv $importFile | select *

foreach($user in $users){
$DisplayName = $user.'Display Name'
$Managers = $user.'Manager'

$Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName 
$EmployeeManagers = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $Managers

Set-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.ObjectId -RefObjectId $EmployeeManagers.ObjectId
}

foreach ($user in $users) {get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.objectid}
```

This is returning the same manager for all the users even though the manager header in the CSV file has different entries for each user.

Comment: try `foreach ($user in $users) {get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $user.objectid} `

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work but Prasoons answer was in fact correct. its the way I was trying to return ```foreach ($user in $users) {get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.objectid} ``` but its fine i verified in active directory and its working perfectly. thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

in case its helpful for anyone else, Prasoons answer was 100% correct, and once I added the last line back into the loop it worked perfectly. Final working code is below. Thanks Prasoon!

```
$importFile = "c:\report\Users.csv"
$users = import-csv $importFile | select *

foreach($user in $users){
$DisplayName = $user.'Display Name'
$Managers = $user.'Manager'

$Employees = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $displayName 
$EmployeeManagers = Get-AzureADUser | where displayname -EQ $Managers

Set-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.ObjectId -RefObjectId $EmployeeManagers.ObjectId
get-AzureADUserManager -objectid $employees.objectid 
}
```